# Geting value of the input that is clicked through knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, knockout.js

I am pretty new to knockout, so I am trying to figure out how to make my small application working. Essentially, I want a Google Map to zoom in into a place from my list on click. Google Map part is working. I have created a list that I fill in using knockout foreach method. Then, I have binded the value of items to my functions, but it keeps throwing error:

"knockout-3.4.2.js:1871 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return places }"
Message: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return zoomToPlace }"
Message: zoomToPlace is not defined"

Here is my html for this part:

```
<div class="scroll" id="myUL">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: places">
     <li>
       <input data-bind="value: title, click: zoomToPlace" type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-link">
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my js:

```
function PlacesList() {
var self = this;
self.places = ko.observableArray(locations);
self.title = ko.observable();
self.zoomToPlace = function() {
    // Initialize the geocoder.
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // Get the place.
    var address = this.title();
    // Geocode the address/area entered to get the center. Then, center the map on it and zoom in
    geocoder.geocode({
        address: address,
        componentRestrictions: {
            locality: 'North York'
        }
    }, function(results, status) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(15);
    });
}
}

ko.applyBindings(new PlacesList(), document.getElementById("myUL"));
```

Thank you, your input will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `zoomToPlace` to `$parent.zoomToPlace`.

Inside a `forEach` loop the context is the current `places` item. Since `zoomToPlace` isn't a method of the items in `places` you were getting an error.

Comment: I can't express how much I am thankful to you! It has worked!